# SpriteKit tiles showing in editor but not in simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

I'm trying to setup an SKTileMap and, in the editor, it's working fine, as you can see here:
[image: Working Images]

However when I run this in the simulator, this happens:
[image: Broken Images]

I've tried removing the app from the simulator and cleaning the project (As I've read that triggers the assets to get rebuilt)... no dice.

Any thoughts on my next debugging steps?!

The original images are PNG's inside an XCAsset, in a folder. Each one is Lossless and the folder Provides a Namespace. These are then used in a tile map like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh it's the Namespace!

I disabled it and rebuilt the tiles. Works fine now.